# Why is the wrong MIB being used during snmpwalk?

Tags: snmp, printer, mib, datadog

Running snmp walk for the following OID `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9`, which belongs to `PRINTER-MIB` under `prtMarkerSuppliesLevel`, is returning `SNMPv2-SMI` values. I imagine they are correct, but why is the SNMPv2-SMI MIB being referenced here?

I'm running DataDog agent on a mac, and have downloaded and placed PRINTER-MIB in the appropriate location: /usr/share/snmp/mibs. (The DataDog agent is failing to collect the metric, as it seems I need to format MIBs in python, but that is another problem to be dealt with after this one).

Output is as follows:

`snmpwalk -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.14 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9
 SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 800
 SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: 200
 SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: 4000
 SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.4 = INTEGER: 2000
 SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.5 = INTEGER: 2400`

Answer (score 1):

I don't use datadog nor am I an SNMP expert but it seems that 'SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2' is a (sort of) [short hand for the first part of your requested OID '1.3.6.1.2.1'](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.2.1). If you follow the previous link you will see that 43 is listed as the default printer MIB. If you replace 'SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2' with '1.3.6.1.2.1' on all the answers you will arrive at the same OID as is [listed in OIDview for prtMarkerSuppliesLevel](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/Printer-MIB.html) on the default printer MIB.

Answer (score 0):

snmpwalk won't use PRINTER-MIB unless you tell it to.

View the manage for snmpcmd, look for the -m and -M options.

snmwalk will actually decode PRINTER-MIB if you reference it in the request:

(OID referenced via numeric notation)

```
bash-3.2$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.1.14 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 90
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: 30
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: 40
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.4 = INTEGER: 30
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.11.1.1.9.1.5 = INTEGER: 90
```

(OID referenced via symbolic notation)

```
bash-3.2$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.1.14 Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1
(bunch of error messages for missing MIBS that PRINTER-MIB referenced deleted)
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = INTEGER: 90
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.2 = INTEGER: 30
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.3 = INTEGER: 40
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.4 = INTEGER: 30
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.5 = INTEGER: 90
```

(OID referenced via numeric notation, but force load of Printer-MIB)

```
bash-3.2$ snmpwalk -m +Printer-MIB -v2c -c public 192.168.1.14 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9
(bunch of error messages for missing MIBS that PRINTER-MIB referenced deleted)
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = INTEGER: 90
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.2 = INTEGER: 30
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.3 = INTEGER: 40
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.4 = INTEGER: 30
Printer-MIB::prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.5 = INTEGER: 90
```

using "-m all" works too.

Wow, our printers have the same IP address.

--Ken